# Ignore files in SVN using git-svn

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I'm on a team who's using SVN, and I'm using git, and so I used `git-svn` to pull down the repository and do my changes. To take care of ignoring in git, I made a `.gitignore` file in the main directory of the branch. How do I accomplish the same thing with `git-svn` such that I tell SVN to ignore certain files and directories, like `.gitignore`, `.git/`, etc.?

I did not pull down using SVN, so there is no `.svn/` directory; I pulled using `git svn fetch` after initailizing the repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't SVN-client (and SVN working Copy) **you can't set svn:ignore property**, because *git-svn provide only RO-access* to *any* SVN-properties.

In common case `.gitignore` file (with caution) can be used as source for svn:ignore patterns in `svn ps` command in `-F` option

Comment: Ah okay, is there a way to update or init SVN in this directory so I don't have to re-get the repo?

Comment: @JoshuaSmock - no, you must `svn co` in order to have WC... and mixed WCs (SVN+<anything>) in one dir is, in common, bad and error-prone style